# CONCAT and INNER JOIN Heirachical Query - Adding a sibling table

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below creates a hierarchical relationship with tables and records:

```
program -> program_outcome_group -> program_outcome -> unit -> leaning_event
```

Based on the following tables structures:

```
Table program:
        +------------+----------------+
        | program_pk |  program_name  |         
        +------------+----------------+
        
Table program_outcome_group: 
        +--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
        | program_outcome_group_pk |  program_outcome_group | program_fk |            
        +--------------------------+------------------------+------------+
        
Table program_outcome:         
        +--------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+
        | program_outcome_pk | program_outcome | program_outcome_group_fk |          
        +--------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+

Table unit:         
        +---------+-----------+
        | unit_pk | unit_name |          
        +---------+-----------+

Table program_outcome_unit_lookup:     
        +--------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
        | program_outcome_unit_lookup_pk | program_outcome_fk  | unit_fk |            
        +--------------------------------+---------------------+---------+
    
Table learning_event:     
        +-------------------+---------------------+---------+
        | learning_event_pk | learning_event_name | unit_fk |            
        +-------------------+---------------------+---------+       

Table learning_event_program_outcome_lookup:     
        +------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
        | learning_event_program_outcome_lookup_pk | learning_event_fk | program_outcome_fk |            
        +------------------------------------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

The query below works for this.

I now want to add a table `assessment` which would be a sibling to table `learning_event`:

```
program -> program_outcome_group -> program_outcome -> unit -> leaning_event
                                                            -> assessment
```

Along with the `assessment` table, there is another lookup table:

```
Table assessment:     
        +---------------+------------+---------+
        | assessment_pk | assessment | unit_fk |            
        +---------------+------------+---------+       

Table assessment_program_outcome_lookup:     
        +--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+
        | assessment_program_outcome_lookup_pk | assessment_fk | program_outcome_fk |            
        +--------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

How should the query below be changed to add the new sibling table and lookup table?

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', p.program_pk) AS global_id,
           p.program_name AS name,
           NULL AS parent_global_id
    FROM program p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pog.program_outcome_group_pk) AS global_id,
           pog.program_outcome_group AS name,
           CONCAT('program:', pog.program_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome_group pog
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', po.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', po.program_outcome) AS global_id,
           po.program_outcome AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', po.program_outcome_group_fk) AS parent_global_id
    FROM program_outcome po
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro.program_outcome, ',unit:', u.unit_full_name) AS global_id,
           u.unit_full_name AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro.program_outcome) AS parent_global_id
    FROM unit u
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome pro ON pro.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name, ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id,
           le.learning_event_name AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_full_name) AS parent_global_id
    FROM learning_event le
    INNER JOIN unit u2 ON le.unit_fk = u2.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome pro2 ON pro2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
    JOIN learning_event_program_outcome_lookup lepol 
      ON lepol.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk 
     AND lepol.program_outcome_fk = pro2.program_outcome_pk
```

See [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mFvmWxFYgGNrcHiyjz4BP9/0)

Comment: What are the roles of those new tables? Will it be used to filter a specific result set or would it just return additional information for the end result?

Comment: Just noticed I had an old query in the question.   Now updated that.   The two new tables would essentially be the same in functionality as the two tables for learning events (the learning_event table and associated lookup table, learning_event_program_outcome_lookup).  The new assessment tables would provide siblings learning_event and assessment.  So the last SELECT could be replicated, and learning_event replaced by assessment and then the assessment lookup table added in the same way as the other lookup table.  Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Also the table assessment is the same in functionality as the table learning event, they would be siblings.  The lookup tables for each of those tables are there to filter the results from the two sibling tables based on relationships to program_outcome_fk in the lookup tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t even need to understand the previous sql,just change the name is ok

```sql
 union all
    SELECT 
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name, ',assessment:', t1.assessment) AS global_id,
           t1.assessment AS name,
           CONCAT('program_outcome_group:', pro2.program_outcome_group_fk, ',program_outcome:', pro2.program_outcome, ',unit:', u2.unit_name) AS parent_global_id
    FROM assessment t1
    INNER JOIN unit u2 ON t1.unit_fk = u2.unit_pk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_unit_lookup uup ON u2.unit_pk = uup.unit_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome pro2 ON pro2.program_outcome_pk = uup.program_outcome_fk
    INNER JOIN program_outcome_group pog2 ON pro2.program_outcome_group_fk = pog2.program_outcome_group_pk
    JOIN assessment_program_outcome_lookup t5 
      ON t5.assessment_fk = t1.assessment_pk 
     AND t5.program_outcome_fk = pro2.program_outcome_pk
```